# Atwood's machine doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

The below image is from the book *Concepts of physics* by H.C. Verma.

> [image: 1]

The last line says that if pulley $B$ is also light then $T_1=T_2$

I don't understand how this happens.

Comment: @quirkyquark why you don't account frictional force on pulley by the rope

Comment: @quirkyquark Actually, you are assuming that the pulley has very high friction so the rope doesn't slip. At all points on the pulley where the rope goes around it fully, friction cancels the tension. At the end points, where the rope is _just_ lifted off from the pulley, friction vanishes (no normal force), but we still have tension so that the overall torque on the pulley is $(T_1 - T_2 )R$.

Comment: @PraharMitra how does friction cancel tension

Comment: @lalittolani - it would have to otherwise the rope would slip on the pulley. Just imagine the extreme case of zero friction. The rope would move around, but the pulley would not turn at all!

Comment: @PraharMitra see this question, this also confuses me more how does tension pulls the pulley? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648806/how-does-a-string-pulls-pulley-at-both-the-ends

Comment: @lalittolani The comment by DKNguyen answers your question there.

Comment: @if string and pulley is smooth, pulley doesn't rotates. if very high friction is there between them, then rope doesn't slides over pulley right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127053/discussion-between-lalit-tolani-and-prahar-mitra).

Answer (score 0):

By "light" it means the pulley is massless which means it has no inertia. Since it has no inertia it can spin immediately in response to the rope without slip. Similarly, it would be the same as if the spinning wheel in the pulley was instead a fixed, frictionless rod that the rope slide over. Inertia in the spinning wheel or friction in the fixed rod would cause the rope to get "hung up" on the pulley which would allow them to be a bit more independent.

The extreme case would be if friction on the pulley shaft, the moment of inertia of the pulley, or the friction of the rope sliding over a fixed rod that replaced the pulley wheel was infinite. In that case, the wheel never spins and the rope never slides so the masses never move. The masses would just hang there. Obviously the tensions would be different in that case.

Comment: Will angular acceleration not be infinite if mass of pulley and hence it's moment of inertia=zero

Comment: No, because the pulley isn't just having a forced applied to it independent of its displacement. The pulley's rotation is tied connected to the rope via friction and the rope is connected to the masses. The masses can't accelerate infinitely so neither can the pulley. The displacement of the masses is tied to the angular displacement of the pulleys. As long as there any friction between rope and pulley, even very low friction so lots of slip, the pulley's acceleration is limited from infinite.

Comment: If pulley is frictionless, why will it spin?

Comment: @lalittolani You aren't being careful enough with your words and you aren't reading what I wrote carefully enough. You say "*if the pulley is frictionless*". Frictionless where? I specifically said "*as long as there is friction between rope and pulley*"

Comment: @lalittolani The friction between the shaft and pulley wheel can be frictionless, or the friction between rope and the pulley can be frictionless, OR you could just replace the spinning wheel on the pulley with a fixed rod that is frictionless with the rope. These are all the same thing if the pulley is massless because it doesn't matter if the pulley is spinning or not. All that matters is that the rope can move back and forth. But just because the pulley-shaft is frictionless doesn't mean the rope-pulley is frictionless, and it will still spin in that case even though it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Light pulley means $m = 0$. Then, when you take torques acting upon the pulley (w.r.t. the center of the pulley): $ T_1 R - T_2 R = I \alpha = 0$ (because $m=0 \implies I=0$). Then, $T_1 = T_2$.

Actually this is very similar to saying that if the rope is massless then then tension $T_1$ is the same all along the left rope. In that case, that is derived from Newton's 2nd law (sum of forces). In this case we are using an equation for sum of torques, which is sort of Newton's 2nd law for rotation.